# number possible part of speech of the word

Tags: stanford-nlp

I know how to get pos of a word in the text but I need to know what would be the possible pos of a word in a sentence for example "like" can have 4 part of speechs: verb noun preposition ....
Is it possible to get that from Stanford library?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Stanford CoreNLP doesn't seem to have an interface to WordNet, but it's pretty easy to do this with one of the other small Java WordNet libraries.  For this example, I used [JWI 2.3.3](http://projects.csail.mit.edu/jwi/).

Besides JWI, you'll need to download a copy of the WordNet database. For example, you can download [WordNet-3.0.tar.gz from Princeton](http://wordnetcode.princeton.edu/3.0/).  Untar the dictionary.

The following code includes a function that returns a list of the possible parts of speech for a word:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;

import edu.mit.jwi.Dictionary;
import edu.mit.jwi.item.POS;
import edu.mit.jwi.item.IIndexWord;
import edu.mit.jwi.morph.WordnetStemmer;

public class WNDemo {

  /**
   * Given a dictionary and a word, find all the parts of speech the
   * word can be.
   */
  public static Collection getPartsOfSpeech(Dictionary dict, String word) {
    ArrayList<POS> parts = new ArrayList<POS>();
    WordnetStemmer stemmer = new WordnetStemmer(dict);
    // Check every part of speech.
    for (POS pos : POS.values()) {
      // Check every stem, because WordNet doesn't have every surface
      // form in its database.
      for (String stem : stemmer.findStems(word, pos)) {
        IIndexWord iw = dict.getIndexWord(stem, pos);
        if (iw != null) {
          parts.add(pos);
        }
      }
    }
    return parts;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
      Dictionary dict = new Dictionary(new File("WordNet-3.0/dict"));
      dict.open();
      System.out.println("'like' is a " + getPartsOfSpeech(dict, "like"));
    } catch (IOException e) {
      System.err.println("Error: " + e);
    }
  }
}
```

And the output:

```
'like' is a [noun, verb, adjective]
```

Comment: Thank u very much, but when I use your code I get the problem of  Dictionary cannot be resolved to a type  and WordnetStemmer cannot be resolved to a type and IIndexWord cannot be resolved to a type though I downloaded and imported jwi jar file from http://projects.csail.mit.edu/jwi/

Comment: Are you sure you're using JWI 2.3.3?  This works for me: `curl  'http://projects.csail.mit.edu/jwi/download.php?f=edu.mit.jwi_2.3.3.jar' > edu.mit.jwi_2.3.3.jar`, `javac -cp edu.mit.jwi_2.3.3.jar WNDemo.java`